# How to pass a query string to another page on the same website?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using a plugin that uses `unique user ids (uuid)` to let visitors access some information. They receive this information by email. The whole system is based on wordpress.

This works great, if the visitor opens the direct page with a url containing the query string, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/user_site/?uuid=237237
```

As soon, as the user opens the link and navigates to another page, and then maybe to its user_site, the query string is lost. Its shown in this example:

> **History of opened urls:**
>
> 1. `https://www.example.com/user_site/?uuid=237237`
> 2. `https://www.example.com/another_site` *- bad, the query string is lost*
> 3. `https://www.example.com/user_site` *- no access, who even is this guy?!*

How can I change this and pass (or parse) the query string while the user stays on the site? Or can I even cache it? I can use `php`, `.htaccess` `javascript` or `jQuery` to achieve this.

> **How the history should be:**
>
> 1. `https://www.example.com/user_site/?uuid=237237`
> 2. `https://www.example.com/another_site/?uuid=237237` *- good, still know who you are*
> 3. `https://www.example.com/user_site/?uuid=237237` *- great, come in*

Comment: "After opening another site" - do you mean you navigate away to a completely different site and then navigate back again by some other link, bookmark or back button perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, this was misleading. I have changed it to "another page (same domain)". After returning from a completely different site it could only be solved by using a caching plugin I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `var sections = window.location.split('=')`